# Raster package doesn't work with my shiny server

Tags: r, shiny, leaflet, raster, shiny-server

I am trying to put a script on a shiny server. This script is working well when I type it in the R console. This is a R script using shiny.

```
library(shiny)
library(htmlwidgets)
library(raster)
library(leaflet)
library(sp)
library(RCurl)

# PATHS TO INPUT / OUTPUT FILES
projectPath = "/srv/shiny-server/sample-apps/hello"
imgPath = paste(projectPath,"/test.tif", sep = "")

# load raster image file
r <- raster(imgPath)
pal <- colorNumeric(c("#FF0000", "#666666", "#FFFFFF"), values(r),
                    na.color = "transparent")

r_colors <- rgb(t(col2rgb(colors()) / 255))
names(r_colors) <- colors()

ui <- fluidPage(
  leafletOutput("mymap"),
  p(),
  actionButton("recalc", "New points")
)

server <- function(input, output, session) {

  points <- eventReactive(input$recalc, {
    cbind(rnorm(40) * 2 + 13, rnorm(40) + 48)
  }, ignoreNULL = FALSE)

  output$mymap <- renderLeaflet({
    leaflet() %>%
  addTiles() %>%
  addRasterImage(r, colors=pal, opacity = 0.9, maxBytes = 123123123) %>%
  addLegend(pal = pal, values = values(r), title = "Salut")
  })
}

shinyApp(ui, server)
```

This is some a random script but I need to be able to show a raster file on a leaflet map and I can't make it work with Shiny-server.
This is the error I get :

```
ERROR: Cannot create a RasterLayer object from this file.
```

Answer (score 0):

before this line:

```
r <- raster(imgPath)
```

do

```
print(imgPath)
file.exists(imgPath)
```

to check if all is correct. And check if rgdal can be found:

```
library(rgdal)
```

Comment: I did install the rgdal library but for the print, I dont know how to print it since its on the webbrowser :/ The only thing I can say is that if I copy and paste this code in a R console, it does work